# How to generate initialization of class fields with Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I know how to create a local variable inside a method, for example this:

```
LocalDeclarationStatement(VariableDeclaration(IdentifierName("MyClass"))
            .WithVariables(SingletonSeparatedList(VariableDeclarator(Identifier("nameOfvariable"))
                .WithInitializer(
                    EqualsValueClause(
                        ObjectCreationExpression(IdentifierName("MyClass")).WithArgumentList(arguments)
                            .WithNewKeyword(Token(SyntaxKind.NewKeyword)))))));
```

would give me:

```
MyClass nameOfvariable = new MyClass();
```

But say that I already created a field and now I simply want to initialize it (in a method, constructor or anything) like this:

```
nameOfVariable = new MyClass();
```

How do I do this? My guess it have to do with the VariableDeclerator but I can't find a way to get it right so I can add it to a list that contains StatementSyntaxes. I can change the VariableDecleration to "VariableDeclaration(IdentifierName(""))" too but that gives me an ugly extra space infront of the statement.

It seems like I struggle with some really basic stuff of Roslyn and I try to check http://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/ but that feels like the forced way to do it (feels like it create a lot more code than necessary).

Update: Should clarify that I know how to create method/constructors. I'm only looking for a way to initialize a field when I only have access to the field name and field type. So the only code I want to generate is this:

```
myField = new MyField();
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks for mentioning http://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/. I did not know about it.  Despite some of your reservations, it looks to be a very helpful tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you're almost there, you just need to create all that. This should do what you're interested in:

```
const string source = @"
using System;

class MyClass
{
    void Method()
    {
        MyClass nameOfVariable;
    }
}
";
var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(source);
var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("MyCompilation", new[] { tree }, new[] { MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location) });
var semanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);
var root = tree.GetRoot();

var local = root.DescendantNodes().OfType<LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax>().First();
var declaration = local.Declaration;
var declarator = declaration.Variables.First();

var identifier = SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("MyClass");
var objectCreationExpression = SyntaxFactory.ObjectCreationExpression(identifier, SyntaxFactory.ArgumentList(), null);
var equalsValueClause = SyntaxFactory.EqualsValueClause(objectCreationExpression);
var newDeclarator = declarator.WithInitializer(equalsValueClause).WithAdditionalAnnotations(Formatter.Annotation);
var newRoot = root.ReplaceNode(declarator, newDeclarator);
var formattedRoot = Formatter.Format(newRoot, Formatter.Annotation, new AdhocWorkspace());

Console.WriteLine(formattedRoot.GetText());
Console.Read();
```

Some explanation: you create a new identifier `MyClass` which will be used in your `ObjectCreationExpression`. Then you wrap all that in an `EqualsValueClause` and you set that as an initializer to your declarator. We also add the `Formatter` annotation to this node so we can format it later and don't end up with whitespace issues.

All that's left then is replacing the node in your original tree, formatting it and you're done:

[image]

### -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

If you instead mean that you want to put the assignment on its own separately from the declaration then you have to create a new `AssignmentExpression` and wrap it inside a `ExpressionStatement`. Typically expressions and statements are distinct concepts but this `ExpressionStatement` allows us to treat an expression as a statement which is important because a method's body only accepts statements.

In code, it looks like this:

```
internal static void Execute()
{
    const string source = @"
using System;

class MyClass
{
    void Method()
    {
        MyClass nameOfVariable, another;
    }
}
";
    var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(source);
    var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("MyCompilation", new[] { tree }, new[] { MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location) });
    var semanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);
    var root = tree.GetRoot();

    var local = root.DescendantNodes().OfType<LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax>().First();
    var method = local.Ancestors().OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>().First();

    var variableIdentifier = SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("nameOfVariable");
    var classIdentifier = SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("MyClass");
    var objectCreationExpression = SyntaxFactory.ObjectCreationExpression(classIdentifier, SyntaxFactory.ArgumentList(), null);
    var assignment = SyntaxFactory.AssignmentExpression(SyntaxKind.SimpleAssignmentExpression, variableIdentifier, objectCreationExpression);
    var expressionStatement = SyntaxFactory.ExpressionStatement(assignment).WithAdditionalAnnotations(Formatter.Annotation);
    var newMethod = method.AddBodyStatements(expressionStatement);

    var newRoot = root.ReplaceNode(method.Body, newMethod.Body);
    var formattedRoot = Formatter.Format(newRoot, Formatter.Annotation, new AdhocWorkspace());

    Console.WriteLine(formattedRoot.GetText());
    Console.Read();
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer but not really what I am looking for. I maybe should update my title because I don't have any problem with creating methods/classes . The problem is that I created everything before and now I simply want to initialie the field ("nameOfVariable = new MyClass") and the only thing I have access to is variable name + type. Your example code is pretty much doing the same as my example (but in a different order).

Comment: What's the problem? You say you want to initialize a field, this is exactly what it's doing.

Comment: Yes, but you're creating the object and initializing it on the same row (the same as my example code). The problem is that I want to create the object and initialize it on another row/place.

Comment: Oh okay. So you want two statements: `MyClass nameOfVariable;` and `nameOfVariable = new MyClass()`?

Comment: Exactly, but found a way to do it now. Posted my own answer that use "AssignmentExpression" which seems to work. But still, thanks for your help!

Comment: Yep, just updated my answer with that same approach ;-)

Answer (score 1):

After some more trying and looking I found the answer. There is something called "AssignmentExpression" that you can use.

Here is an example how to use it:

```
ExpressionStatement(AssignmentExpression(SyntaxKind.SimpleAssignmentExpression, IdentifierName("myField"),
            ObjectCreationExpression(IdentifierName("MyClass")).WithArgumentList(arguments)
                .WithNewKeyword(Token(SyntaxKind.NewKeyword))));
```

This would give you:

```
myField = new Myclass();
```

So now it's easy to seperate creation and assignment/initialization to two different statements.

Note that I'm using "using static Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SyntaxFactory;" so I don't have to write SyntaxFactory all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can goto "http://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/" and paste your code in the small little textbox and click "Get Roslyn API calls to generate this code".

(I can generate the code you posted above, but it is kinda long. so i use a simple example.

For example, let's say you paste "DateTime mydate2 = new DateTime()", the tool will generate the following code :-

```
LocalDeclarationStatement(
VariableDeclaration(
    IdentifierName("DateTime"))
.WithVariables(
    SingletonSeparatedList<VariableDeclaratorSyntax>(
        VariableDeclarator(
            Identifier("mydate2"))
        .WithInitializer(
            EqualsValueClause(
                ObjectCreationExpression(
                    IdentifierName("DateTime"))
                .WithArgumentList(
                    ArgumentList())))))).WithSemicolonToken(
MissingToken(SyntaxKind.SemicolonToken)).NormalizeWhitespace()
```

Then you just have to fix up the code using SyntaxFactory, for example :-

```
   var myDeclaratyion = SyntaxFactory.LocalDeclarationStatement(
SyntaxFactory.VariableDeclaration(
    SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("DateTime")).
WithVariables(
    SyntaxFactory.SingletonSeparatedList<VariableDeclaratorSyntax>(
        SyntaxFactory.VariableDeclarator(
            SyntaxFactory.Identifier("mydate2")).
        WithInitializer(
            SyntaxFactory.EqualsValueClause(
                SyntaxFactory.ObjectCreationExpression(
                    SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("DateTime"))
                .WithArgumentList(
                    SyntaxFactory.ArgumentList())))))).WithSemicolonToken(SyntaxFactory.MissingToken(SyntaxKind.SemicolonToken)).NormalizeWhitespace();
```